# Error Creating Database Configuration in Cordys

Tags: cordys-opentext

I was trying to create WS AppServer for cordys.I tried to connfigure a new Database using the DB Configuration wizard.But I got the following error while creating the DataBase

```
<ErrorDetails>
  <Request>
    <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <SOAP:Header xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <header xmlns="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/">
          <Logger xmlns="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/" />
        </header>
        <i18n:international xmlns:i18n="http://www.w3.org/2005/09/ws-i18n">
          <locale xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/09/ws-i18n">en-US</locale>
        </i18n:international>
      </SOAP:Header>
      <SOAP:Body>
        <TestConnectivity xmlns:xfr="http://schemas.cordys.com/1.0/xforms/runtime" xmlns="http://schemas.cordys.com/DSOConfig/1.0">
          <dso>
            <name>Test#MDMPOC</name>
            <type>Relational</type>
            <description>Test</description>
            <organization>MDMPOC</organization>
            <configuration>
              <component name="Connection pool">
                <jdbcDriver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</jdbcDriver>
                <driverName>JDBC</driverName>
                <jdbcDriverXAClass>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</jdbcDriverXAClass>
                <defaultDatabase>Test</defaultDatabase>
                <connectionString>
                  <![CDATA[jdbc:mysql://<<server_name>>:<<port_no>>/<<db>>?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8]]>
                </connectionString>
                <userName>usr</userName>
                <password>dXNy</password>
                <level />
              </component>
            </configuration>
          </dso>
        </TestConnectivity>
      </SOAP:Body>
    </SOAP:Envelope>
  </Request>
  <Response>
    <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <SOAP:Header xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <header xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/">
          <msg-id>00505685-3bf1-11e4-e1f5-714467085f15</msg-id>
          <license>License has expired since 615 day(s)</license>
        </header>
      </SOAP:Header>
      <SOAP:Body>
        <SOAP:Fault>
          <faultcode xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">ns0:Server</faultcode>
          <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Configuration validation was not successful.</faultstring>
          <faultactor>http://schemas.cordys.com/DSOConfig/1.0</faultactor>
          <detail>
            <cordys:FaultDetails xmlns:cordys="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/">
              <cordys:LocalizableMessage xmlns:cordys="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/">
                <cordys:MessageCode xmlns:cordys="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/">Cordys.DSOConfig.Messages.validationFailed</cordys:MessageCode>
              </cordys:LocalizableMessage>
            </cordys:FaultDetails>
            <cordys:FaultRelatedException xmlns:cordys="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/">
              <![CDATA[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create dso:

<error
    TYPE="Enumeration">
    <elem>Error occurred while connecting to the database server. com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "<<port_no>>"'.</elem>
    <cordys:LocalizableMessage
        xmlns:cordys="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/">
        <cordys:MessageCode>Cordys.Database.Native.Messages.dbConnectionError</cordys:MessageCode>
        <cordys:Insertion>com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "<<port_no>>"'.</cordys:Insertion>
    </cordys:LocalizableMessage>
</error>
(-1)
    at com.eibus.applicationconnector.sql.DBConnection.initialize(DBConnection.java:204)
    at com.eibus.applicationconnector.sql.DBConnection.<init>(DBConnection.java:116)
    at com.eibus.applicationconnector.sql.WCPDBConnection.<init>(WCPDBConnection.java:93)
    at com.eibus.applicationconnector.sql.LocalConnection.<init>(DBConnectionPool.java:79)
    at com.eibus.applicationconnector.sql.DBConnectionPool.createConnection(DBConnectionPool.java:1945)
    at com.eibus.applicationconnector.sql.DBConnectionPool.initialize(DBConnectionPool.java:1811)
    at com.eibus.applicationconnector.sql.DBConnectionPool.<init>(DBConnectionPool.java:1326)
    at com.eibus.applicationconnector.sql.DBConnectionPool.<init>(DBConnectionPool.java:1132)
    at com.eibus.applicationconnector.sql.DBConnectionPool._createInstance(DBConnectionPool.java:1111)
    at com.cordys.dsoconfig.types.CordysDBSO.testConnectivity(CordysDBSO.java:74)
    at com.cordys.dsoconfig.DSOConfigService.testConnectivity(DSOConfigService.java:117)
    at com.cordys.dsoconfig.DSOConfigSOAPService.testConnectivity(DSOConfigSOAPService.java:225)
    at com.cordys.dsoconfig.DSOConfigSOAPService.process(DSOConfigSOAPService.java:344)
    at com.eibus.soap.SOAPTransaction.handleBodyBlock(SOAPTransaction.java:1305)
    at com.eibus.soap.SOAPTransaction.<init>(SOAPTransaction.java:602)
    at com.eibus.soap.SOAPTransaction.<init>(SOAPTransaction.java:175)
    at com.eibus.soap.Processor.onReceive(Processor.java:970)
    at com.eibus.soap.Processor.onReceive(Processor.java:943)
    at com.eibus.connector.nom.Connector.onReceive(Connector.java:417)
    at com.eibus.transport.Middleware$NonTransactionalWorkerThreadBody.run(Middleware.java:1758)
    at com.eibus.util.threadpool.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:64)
]]>
            </cordys:FaultRelatedException>
          </detail>
        </SOAP:Fault>
      </SOAP:Body>
    </SOAP:Envelope>
  </Response>
</ErrorDetails>
```

I'm new to cordys concepts and having difficulty in trying to understand it.Why is it required to provide DB configuration in WS Appserver details? Is Ws AppServer different from other application servers?

Comment: I hope its too late for the solution but this question is open ended. Please try to close the subject by approving/providing the answer or if you are still facing this problem, please mention the connection string url for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Please mention the relevant port number during the database setup and try again.
WS AppServer is used to create web services, through which we can access the data in the database. Please go through the cordys documentation for details.